# Detecting empty cells

Tags: php, html, sql

I had to display a table using php and html, that select data from sql server. Their is a cell called echo photo that sometimes is empty, and sometimes is loaded with an image. How to change my code to test:

```
if (it is empty){
 echo "No echo files";
}
else{
<a href='download_PopUp.php?data=<?php echo $dataFile2; ?>'>Click to download</a>
}
```

My php and html codes are:

```
<?php
...
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$data =$rows['echo_photo'];
$dataFile = str_replace('/', '\\', $data);
...
?>
```

here in this td of html table I want to put if else conditions

```
<td align="center"><a href='download_PopUp.php?data=<?php echo $dataFile2; ?>'>Click to download</a></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if (!empty($data)) : ?>
    <td align="center"><a href='download_PopUp.php?data=<?php echo $dataFile2; ?>'>Click to download</a></td>
<?php else: ?>
    <td align="center">No Data Available</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you change the query.

```
Select * FROM table WHERE echo_photo NOT LIKE ''
```

Than you will only get the values that exists

Otherwise you can do it with a if statement like:

```
if(!empty($data)){
// echo html code
}else{
echo "No Data Found!";
```

Comment: No, I need to display all data including echo_photo are empty or not, and where it is empty i put a single text. And when it is available I put the downloadable link to it. I think someone posted the answer now. Thank you all.